# Column Group Filtering

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset with a 'Type' Column. Let's call these Types A B and C.
I want to present aggregates for the different columns, AND I want a total column but ONLY for Types A and B. 
I've put in a Column Group, which works fine for showing the three types. I've also added an adjacent column group (grouped on "1" as a dummy), and added a group filter which has Type in A, B.
However, this second adjacent column group still produces totals for all types A B and C. It is as if the filter is being ignored.

What am I missing here?

I've tried different expressions in the column group filter but none seem to work. I've also looked at other questions but none seem to be the same as mine here.

Comment: Can't you just use the expression `=IIF(Fields!Type.Value <> "C", Sum(Fields!ValuesToBeSummed.Value), 0)` in the aggregate column?

Comment: Actually you'd need the SUM outside of the IIF `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value <> "C", Fields!ValuesToBeSummed.Value, 0)) `